# Laravel 5.4 How to responses JSON with Relationship?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to response JSON with Laravel that I have CategoryModel belongTo SongModel.

This is my CategoryModel

```
class CategoryModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
    ];

    public function song()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SongModel::class);
    }
}
```

And this is my SongModel

```
class SongModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'songs';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'url',
        'categories_id',
        'singers_id',
        'types_id',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CategoryModel::class);
    }
}
```

I want to response JSON with the relationship. I wrote:

```
class SongController extends Controller
{
    public function index(SongModel $songModel)
    {
        $song = $songModel->category()->get();
        return response()->json(["DATA" => $song], 201);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To do this you will just need to load the relationship before you return the response:

```
public function index(SongModel $songModel)
{
    $songModel->load('category');

    return response()->json(["DATA" => $songModel], 201);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading

Hope this helps!

Comment: It shows me that category Null.
{"DATA":{"category":null}}

Comment: @Vichit Sorry, I wasn't meant to assign the load to `song`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: For example, I want to respond like this
{
    "DATA": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": see you again,
            "url": "......."
            "category_id": 2,
            "category": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "....",
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @Vichit Have you updated both parts of my edit i.e. you should be returning `$songModel` not `$song`?

Comment: @Vichit Did this answer you question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `return response()->json(["DATA" => $songModel->load('category')->toArray()], 201);`

Comment: It shows me like this: {
    "DATA": {
        "category": null
    }
}

Comment: @Vichit Oh, I see. Maybe `$songModel` in your controller is null, so it returns null in the response.

Comment: I think your code for route model binding is defined improperly.

Comment: @ImPerat0R_2 So, What can I do?

Comment: This is my route.
Route::resource('/api/v1/songs', 'SongController', ['only' => ['index', 'show',]]);

Comment: In index function, write like this. public function index()
    {
        $songs = SongModel::get()->load('category');
        return response()->json(["DATA" => $songs], 201);
    }

Comment: Got all but category null.
{
  "DATA": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "រាំតាមពូ",
            "url": "http://download1347.mediafireuserdownload.com/fwcuyy35rirg/u8n19g4e111eokw/audio.mp3",
            "categories_id": 2,
            "singers_id": 1,
            "types_id": 1,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "category": null
        },
    ]
}

Comment: Default foreign key is not 'categories_id', so you should write additional foreign key. return $this->belongsTo(CategoryModel::class, 'categories_id');

Comment: Ok, thank you very much ImPerat0R. I got the best answer from you.

Answer (score 0):

**OR**, you can use `with('song')`

```
lass SongController extends Controller
{
    public function index(SongModel $songModel)
    {
        $song = $songModel::with('song')->get();
        return response()->json(["DATA" => $song], 201);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank so much for your answer:D